# Почему название кнопки берется из другого блока?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var btn = this;
    if (btn.loaded) {
      $(btn).prev("div").html(btn.originalContent);
      btn.loaded = false;
      $(btn).text('Сравнить цены');
    } else {
      btn.originalContent = $(btn).prev("div").html();
      $(btn).prop('disabled', true);
      $.get($(btn).data("url"), function(html) {
        $(btn).prev("div").html(html);
        $(btn).prop('disabled', false).text('Закрыть');
        btn.loaded = true;
      });
    }
  });

  $("button").click(function() {
    var btns = this;
    if (btns.loaded) {
      $(btns).prev("uve").html(btns.originalContent);
      btns.loaded = false;
      $(btns).text('Уведомление');
    } else {
      btns.originalContent = $(btns).prev("uve").html();
      $(btns).prop('disabled', true);
      $.get($(btns).data("url"), function(html) {
        $(btns).prev("uve").html(html);
        $(btns).prop('disabled', false).text('Закрыть');
        btns.loaded = true;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
<button data-url="aviabiletyadler.php?a=1" style="font-size: inherit;float: left;display: block;margin: 0px auto;padding: 8px;background: #fff;border-top: 5px solid #4682b4;color: wheat;cursor: pointer;border-radius: 5px;color: #40406f;">Сравнить цены</button>
<div id="uve"></div>
<button data-url="/uvedomlenie.php?a=11" style="font-size: inherit;float: left;display: block;margin: 0px auto;padding: 8px;background: #fff;border-top: 5px solid #4682b4;color: wheat;cursor: pointer;border-radius: 5px;color: #40406f;">Уведомить</button>
```

Как разделить эти блоки чтоб кнопки при открывании и закрывании имели названия исходя из своих `ID` и своего скрипта? У меня сейчас если открыть кнопку `Уведомление` открывается правильный контент, но когда закрываю эту кнопку, то она меняет название на `Сравнить цены`

Comment: Ваш код содержит синтаксические ошибки.

Comment: @Igor Одну исправил, вторую непонимаю

Comment: @Igor Я ваш код решил применить для еще одного другого функционала, но у меня не получилось. )

Comment: Потому что сначала надо понять, что этот код делает.

Comment: Во втором обработчике пропущен `if`.

Comment: @Igor Вы правы, но у меня не получается ничего

Comment: @Igor добавил, но все равно ошибки и не работает(

Comment: @Igor не срабатывает(

Comment: Что не срабатывает? Я убрал синтаксические ошибки.

Comment: @Igor Я думал из-за этих ошибок не работает, Вы исправили, думал должно было работать, вот и написал "не срабатывает"

Comment: @Igor Спасибо что убрали ошибки

Comment: Вы навешиваете по два обработчика на обе кнопки.

Comment: @Igor Я со вчерашнего вечера что-то пытаюсь сделать, но ничего не понимаю и ничего не получается. С JS всегда у меня проблема

Comment: @Igor нужно вот это убраь и в конце скобку? $(document).ready(function() {